# Where and how Python stores yielded data?

Tags: python, memory, generator

Imagine I have a function that look like this:

```
def gen_fn():
  yield from range(10000)
```

And then I assign it to a million variables:

```
d = {}
for x in range(100000):
    d[f'variable{x}'] = fn()
```

Now each variable `variable0` to `variable999999` point to a different generator:

```
d

# 'variable0': <generator object fn at 0x155e40390>,
# 'variable1': <generator object fn at 0x155e405e8>,
# 'variable2': <generator object fn at 0x155e40570>,
# 'variable3': <generator object fn at 0x155e404f8>,
# 'variable4': <generator object fn at 0x155dfe840>,
...
```

I understand that it assigns each `variable` to a separate generator because of the idea behind them, I might want to get `next(d['variable0'])` and not affect the `next(d['variable1'])`, is that right?

Now let's say I run `next(d['variablex']` where is x is a unique number for a random number of `next()` times from the `range(1000000)`, and now each `generator` from the `gen_fn()` yields a different value. I am interested in where does Python keep the track of what is currently yielded from each of the million generators?

Comment: *"I am interested in where does Python keep the track of what is currently yielded from each of the million generators?"* - When you store a million integers in your list, and Python can give you the value of each of them instantly, that's not a surprise to you, I assume. Why would it be surprising that it works the same way for e.g. generators?

Comment: Hi, @Tomalakm, I see generators as more memory efficient as they do not build the whole list, they return only the next value, as I understand. Maybe what I wanted to ask is if calling a value from a list full of values is the same memory efficient as using generators to return the value. For example, I need a 1m values only once, should I use generator or have a list of 1m values, I assume generator as they do not store the values.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis generators are significantly favorable when dealing with such large ranges, as you said because they lazy create the million values instead of keeping them all in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment  `d[f'variable{x}'] = gen_fn()` assigns to each dictionary key a pointer to the generator function.

Calling these functions later is independent:

e.g.

```
# 0
print(next(d['variable0']))

# 0
print(next(d['variable1']))
# 1
print(next(d['variable1']))
```

The generator maintains state according to [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) documentation:

> When a generator function is called, ***it returns an iterator known as a generator***. That generator then controls the execution of the generator function. The execution starts when one of the generator’s methods is called. At that time, the execution proceeds to the first yield expression, where it is suspended again, returning the value of expression_list to the generator’s caller. 
> By suspended, we mean that ***all local state is retained, including the current bindings of local variables, the instruction pointer, the internal evaluation stack, and the state of any exception handling. When the execution is resumed by calling one of the generator’s methods, the function can proceed exactly as if the yield expression were just another external call***. The value of the yield expression after resuming depends on the method which resumed the execution.

Comment: So the following is True: having different generators that currently `yield` the same value will not be the same memory location in Python?

Comment: Correct! @JonasPalačionis The generators iterators are different, so they are independent, as the attached example validates.